# Is an Internet connection required when installing Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualization, virtualbox

I'm installing Ubuntu on a virtual machine. I keep seeing updates that it's "retrieving" this or "retrieving" that. Is it trying to retrieve them from the Internet or just from the installation CD?

When asked what I wanted to install, I selected:
LAMP server
Mail server
OpenSSH server

I hope all these are on the Ubuntu installation CD, because I'm not connected to the Internet during the installation routine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing does not require the internet however fetching packages from Ubuntu servers requires an internet connection to install "LAMP" and such. They are not included on the cd.

Comment: Ouch, so if I was disconnected at the time it was fetching, would it at least give me an error that it couldn't fetch?

Comment: if you "sudo apt-get install apache2" and then when its downloading the package unplug your connection I'm sure you will get an error.